# How to use umake to install the Go language (version 1.8) in Ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: ubuntu-make, golang

I am having trouble with installing the latest version of golang on Ubuntu 16.10. After running the `sudo umake go` command I get the message saying to choose the installation path with the default path suggested as `/home/$user/.local/share/umake/go/go-lang`. This does not appear to be what I want as typing in the `go` command afterwards gives me the message: `The program 'go' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install golang-go`. However, using apt to install golang will only give me the older 1.6 version.

I have tried changing the installation path when using umake, but I then get a message that the directory specified will be deleted and everything in it replaced. I am not sure where to go from here. Thanks in advance.

After making sure I have the latest version (16.11.1) of umake I ran `umake -r go`. Then I tried again and ran `umake go`. This is the error message I got:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/umake/tools.py", line 158, in wrapper
    function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/umake/frameworks/baseinstaller.py", line 409, in decompress_and_install_done
    self.post_install()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/umake/frameworks/go.py", line 75, in post_install
    "GOROOT": {"value": self.install_path, "keep": False}})
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/umake/tools.py", line 450, in add_env_to_user
    with open(profile_filepath, "a", encoding='utf-8') as f:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/$user/.profile'`

After using umake to uninstall go I ran the `sudo chown -R $USER /home/$USER` command, but am still getting the same error when I then run `umake go`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reviewing [umake documents](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make)

Installing `umake` on your system does required using `sudo`

However it is clear that running `umake app-name` should be done as `regular user` and not as `root`.

The proper command which should be executed in order to install `go` is:

```
umake go
```

If you already executed:

```
sudo umake go
```

You might need to remove the previous installation (which was done by `sudo umake go`) before running the `umake go`

**Solving permission issues caused by `sudo umake go`**

The source of the below error seems to be the execution of `umake go` as root.

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/$user/.profile'

In order to solve it, please execute which will change the ownership of the files in your home-directory to be own by you.

assuming that `thomas` is your username, and `/home/thomas` is your home directory, the following should change the ownership of .profile to be `thomas` instead of root

```
sudo chown thomas /home/thomas/.profile
```

- $USER variable should hold your username (you can replace the $USER in the command with your username)

Comment: @Thomas Lloyd - I've updated my answer - to solve the `permission denied` error

Comment: @Thomas Lloyd - did my answer helped you?

Comment: Afraid not. See latest edit.

Comment: @ThomasLloyd - what is the result of `ls -lsa /home/$user/.profile` ?

Comment: 4 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1001 Mar  2 12:45 /home/thomas/.profile

Comment: updated my answer. assuming that `thomas` is your username - Try `sudo chown thomas /home/thomas/.profile`

Comment: Worked perfectly, only thing I would add is that I had to restart or at least logout before the go command worked. Thank you very much.